# How to force compile-time error on a Resharper custom pattern

Tags: resharper, code-analysis

I'm starting out learning how to use Resharper's Code Inspection, namely Custom Patterns. I created a custom pattern where one pattern displays as an error if it is used. I chose the Show As Error severity level. To be specific, I don't want any of our team developers to use the pattern "Task.Factory.StartNew", I want them to use a custom wrapper instead.

I saved the custom pattern and when I test it out, I see that Resharper underlines the code in red, which is what I want. However, is there a way to show this as a compile-time error? In other words, if a developer builds the solution I want this pattern to appear as a compile-time error, and not compile. Right now, if I build the solution, the compiler does not complain, but Resharper shows the code in red.

Comment: ReSharper isn't the compiler, so that wouldn't be possible.  Have you looked into new Roslyn extensions?

Comment: Do you have a link to Roselyn extensions? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=roslyn&DownloadId=822458 might be s good place to start